# Find multiple files containing a certian string and list the files that don't containt the string

Tags: grep

In the midst of building a site checker I have ran unto a problem, the client needs to check all of their pages for certain strings if they are included in the code and then list the files that do not have the code yet.

Tried with multiple grep commands with no success. The `-v` supposedly exports the inverted match of the results, but that does not happen. Currently I am missing the part of the code telling grep to only search in specific files (example files names `code.php`) in all sub folders.

With the current code it searches all the files even unnecessary ones.

`grep -vrn '.' -e "SRING" > list.txt`

I'd like to export a list of files (preferably that it only checks files in all sub folders with the same name) that do not posses the sting that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -c STRING files` will give you a count of lines with `STRING` for each file.

You can optomize it somewhat with `-m1` to stop after the first match.

You can pipe that to sed to grab the files with zero matches:

`grep -cm1 STRING files | sed -n '/:0$/s/:0//p'`

That gets you one file per line.

You can pipe that to `xargs` to merge it into a one-line list.

If your `STRING` is just that and not a regex, you could use the `-F` flag with grep to specify it's a fixed string, and that will also speed things up.   So maybe...

`grep -Fcm1 STRING files | sed -n '/:0$/s/:0//p' > list.txt`

...in that case